# Out of range exception on visual studio Mac but not on vs windows - both 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outofrangeexception

I did the following method to center and underline a title in a console app:

```
public static void ShowTitle(string Title)
    {
        int SpacesBefore = ((Console.BufferWidth - 1) - Title.Length) / 2;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}\n{0}{2}\n", new string(' ', SpacesBefore), Title, new string('=', Title.Length));
    }
```

Which compiles and works on Visual Studio 2017 (windows) but throws an error I can't debug on Mac.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue presumably lies with this calculation:

```
int SpacesBefore = ((Console.BufferWidth - 1) - Title.Length) / 2;
```

The problem is caused by one of two things: either the console character width (`BufferWidth`) is smaller on MacOS, or your Title is longer. Imagine that `Title` length of 5, and `BufferWidth` of 10:

```
SpacesBefore = ((10 - 1) - 5) / 2 = 2
```

Now imagine that on Mac OS `BufferWidth` is 4:

```
SpacesBefore = ((4 - 1) - 5) / 2 = -1
```

And now you want to use this to construct a string: `new string(' ', -1)`, so you get your exception.

A quick fix might be to change your calculation to this, to ensure that the value is always >= 0, but I'll leave you to decide how to fix it:

```
int SpacesBefore = Math.Max(0, ((Console.BufferWidth - 1) - Title.Length) / 2);
```

I recommend [learning how to use the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017), since inspecting the value of `SpacesBefore`, and then `BufferWidth` would have allowed you to rapidly locate the source of the problem.